# what do I select for configuring grub-pc after an update?

Tags: grub2

After the update, the configuring grub-pc popped out with the question: What do you want to do about modified configuration file grub?

The help button says: A new version of configuration file`/etc/default/grub` is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified.

What should I select? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you don't think you changed /etc/default/grub yourself, overwrite. using [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=dpkg%20trying%20to%20overwrite%20which%20is%20also%20in%20package) you can find many relevant documents